# Is there a way I can access a static resource in my C# code?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my App.XAML I have this:

```
<Application xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Japanese" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Japanese.App">
<Application.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="TextColor1">#123456</Color>
```

I can access this value in XAML like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource TextColor1}" />
</Style>
```

But is there also a way that I can access this in my back end C#

```
vm.C1BtnLabelTextColor = phrase.C1 == true ? Color.FromHex("#123456") : Color.FromHex("#0000FF");
```

For example here I would like to replace:

```
Color.FromHex("#123456")
```

with the value of the StaticResource

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> ResourceDictionary is a repository for resources that are used by a
>   Xamarin.Forms application. Typical resources that are stored in a
>   ResourceDictionary include styles, control templates, data templates,
>   colors, and converters.
>
> In XAML, resources that are stored in a ResourceDictionary can then be
>   retrieved and applied to elements by using the StaticResource markup
>   extension. In C#, resources can also be defined in a
>   ResourceDictionary and then retrieved and applied to elements by using
>   a string-based indexer. However, there's little advantage to using a
>   ResourceDictionary in C#, as shared objects can simply be stored as
>   fields or properties, and accessed directly without having to first
>   retrieve them from a dictionary.

In short: `ResourceDictionary` is a `Dictionary`.
To read a value from a `Dictionary` you have to provide a `Key`. In your case the `Key` is "TextColor1". So using C# here is how you could read the value from `Application.Resources`:

```
var txtColor1 = (Color) Application.Current.Resources["TextColor1"];
```

Please note that you have to cast the returned value to a desired type, thats because the `Dictionary` is "generic".

You could also create an `Extension Method` if you have to reuse it in your project.

Source: [Official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries)

Answer (score 5):

You can access like this:

```
Application.Current.Resources["TextColor1"];
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution proposed here (`Application.Current.Resources["TextColor1"];`) works only if you don't have `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`, otherwise, you need the following approach:

```cs
// helper method
private object GetResourceValue(string keyName)
{
    // Search all dictionaries
    if (Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue(keyName, out var retVal)) {}
    return retVal;
}
```

Exemple how to use:

```cs
ButtonColor = (Color) GetResourceValue("Primary");
```

This method will assure that all merged resources are iterated to find your current resource.

Reference: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/146001/how-to-get-a-rsource-from-an-mergeddictionary-in-c-code

Comment: With .NET MAUI, this technique work fine in Windows. On Android the out var is always null. Does your code work on Android with .NET MAUI?

Answer (score -2):

This definitely works better especially when you are using MergedDictionaries

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31003359)