# Why doesn't (Style)Application.Current.Resources["FrameBorder"] let me access a resource in my ResourceDirectory

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created a resource in the file `FrameRes.xaml` like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
                    x:Class="Japanese.Resources.FrameRes">
    <Style x:Key="FrameBorder" TargetType="Frame">
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="HasShadow" Value="false" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0" />
        <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{DynamicResource LineColor}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Start" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and this is contained inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Application xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Japanese" 
             xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="Japanese.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/FooterRes.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/FrameRes.xaml" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

When I try to access this in C# like this then it fails and says there's no reference to FrameBorder:

```
var fb2 = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["FrameBorder"];
```

When I try to access this in C# like this it works:

```
Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("FrameBorder", out object frameBorder);
var fb = (Style)frameBorder;
```

Does anyone know why the first way doesn't work. It looks the same to me.

Comment: I faced this problem and I posted the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67992365/6846888

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you have it set up, you have a `ResourceDictionary` inside another `ResourceDictionary` with no key/name/reference. When you call `Application.Current.Resources["FrameBorder"];`, you are accessing the upper-most level of the dictionary and looking for `"FrameBorder"`, not its sub-levels. However, calling `TryGetValue` goes through all levels of the Dictionary.

Read through the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2#examples) to understand how to access values from Dictionaries.

---

Ok, so I have played around with the `ResourceDictionary` tags and files, and I can see where you're going wrong.

According to the [Xamarin Forms Docs on `ResourceDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries#merging-dictionaries-in-xamarinforms-30), you can add stand-alone `ResourceDictionary` XAML files to your `App.xaml` like so:

```xml
<App ...>
    <App.Resources>

            <!-- Add more resources here -->

            <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResourceDictionary.xaml" />

            <!-- Add more resources here -->

    </App.Resources>
    ...
</App>
```

You can replace `App` with `ContentPage` or `ContentView`, depending on your use.

### What does this do?

Simply put, this creates a new `ResourceDictionary` object and **merges** other `ResourceDictionary` files into it. Let's go into a bit more detail.

Let's start by looking at the `Application.Current.Resources` property, which is of type [`ResourceDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.resourcedictionary?view=xamarin-forms) and implements `ICollection`, `IDictionary`, and `IResourceDictionary`. Given the interfaces it implements, you can obtain the values by numeric or string ID (ex: `App.Current.Resources[0]` or `App.Current.Resources["LabelStyle"]`). This accesses the **top-level** contents of the dictionary, so only those that have been created in the `<[App/ContentPage/ContentView].Resources>` tag.

You also have a property called `MergedDictionaries`, which implements `ICollection`. This means that you can only access the list items by numeric ID (ex: `MyMergedDictionary[0]`).

When you add a `ResourceDictionary` file like:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary Source="MyResourceDictionary.xaml" />
```

You are actually **merging** this file with the current `ResourceDictionary`. To then access the contents of `MyResourceDictionary` you would call (in C#):

```cs
App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0]["InternalKeyName"]
```

This is probably better explained like so:

```xml
<App ...>
    <App.Resources>

            <!-- Called using App.Current.Resources["PrimaryColor"] -->
            <Color x:Key="PrimaryColor">#2196F3</Color>

            <!-- Called using App.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0]["InternalKeyName"] -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MyResourceDictionary.xaml" />

    </App.Resources>
    ...
</App>
```

### Your case

In your case you have two dictionaries merged into your Application Resources: `FooterRes` and `FrameRes`.

For better management, I would create an `enum` like:

```cs
public enum MergedResourcesEnum
{
    Footer,
    Frame
}
```

and use this enum when calling the resources in C# like so:

```cs
Application
    .Current
    .Resources
    .MergedDictionaries[(int)MergedResourcesEnum.Frame]["FrameBorder"];
```

Comment: I checked the docs but I am still not sure how to access values from inside of the file that I merged into my resource directory. Note that since I posted the question I tried removing the outermost ResourceDirectory as you suggested but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I've jumped into the Xamarin Forms docs, and I've modified my answer by adding a "bit" more information.

Comment: This should the the accepted answer. I am a MSFT Xamarin support engineer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete the outer `ResourceDictionary` tag and both of

```
var fb2 = (Style)Application.Current.Resources["FrameBorder"];
```

and

```
Application.Current.Resources.TryGetValue("FrameBorder", out object frameBorder);
var fb = (Style)frameBorder;
```

work right.

So your xaml code is like this:

(Please ignore the unrelated package name and FooterRes.xaml because I you didnot share your FooterRes.xaml file)

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App75.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/FooterRes.xaml" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: I have tried doing this and it still cannot find the resource

Comment: @Alan2  As I don't have the full code, I just created a simple demo and it worked all right using my solution. Could you share your project so that I would be more easy to solve this problem.